# xelatex file name in cp1251: can't find file

Tags: xetex, input-encodings

I have TeXLive 2019 installed on a Windows machine, the FS encoding is cp1251 (Russian).

I have a file named "ООО *ТРАНССВЯЗЬ*.tex".

When I run:

```
> pdflatex "ООО _ТРАНССВЯЗЬ_.tex"
```

The file is being processed. But there is a message at the end:

```
Transcript written on "╬╬╬ _╥╨└═╤╤┬▀╟▄_.log".
```

The log file name is correct and it is successfully generated.

But when I try

```
> xelatex "ООО _ТРАНССВЯЗЬ_.tex"
```

It fails with a message:

```
! I can't find
file `╧О╠а_╙РM╥С├Я╚Ь_'. <*> "╧О╠а_╙РM╥С├Я╚Ь_"
```

And stops.

Seems that it is awaiting a name in another encoding. What should I do? I can't change the name to ASCII.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you update the TeX Live 2019, I believe that your
problem will be resolved. If you feel cumbersome to
update TeX Live, please do as follows. I assume that
your installation top directory is

```
c:/texlive/2019
```

Make a file

```
c:/texlive/2019/texmf.cnf
```

which contains a line

```
command_line_encoding = utf-8
```